# Image with rounded corner and shadow

Tags: c#, asp.net, gdi

How to make an rounded corner image with shadow effect for an image uploaded by user in C#?

Comment: Do you want to change the uloaded image or just show the image inside a rounded corner div?

Comment: I want to change the image to a rounded corner image with shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use any one of the jQuery plugins to do the job. This has nothing do with c# and is purely a browser-side javascript implementation.

Try this - http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Wrapping_Images_With_A_Drop_Shadow
and this - http://www.bioneural.net/2008/02/13/corners-gradients-and-shadows-with-jquery/

Hope this helps

Arun

Answer (score 0):

If is only for a display purpose then it would be better not to change the original image uploaded by the user. You can display the image inside an HTML element ( like div ) and style the div with rounded corners and shadow.

Here is a nice one

["Sliding Doors" Box– Rounded Corners for All](http://www.vertexwerks.com/tests/sidebox/)

Put the user image inside this one.